# render two different data in react native that comes from two different routes

Tags: node.js, react-native

I'm very new with react native and as a programmer and i'm trying to display user information on screen, with part of the information coming from one route and part of it coming from another route.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { Feather } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { View, FlatList, Image, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Picker } from '@react-native-community/picker';


import styles from './styles';

import api from '../../services/api'

const Main = class Main extends React.Component {  
  
  constructor(props) { 
    super(props)    
    this.state = {
      navigation: props.navigation,
      prestadores: [],
      atividades: [], 
          
    }        
  }

  navigatePerfil(prestador){

    this.state.navigation.navigate('Perfil', { prestador })
    
    
  }


  async componentDidMount() {

    var ativi = await this.loadAtividade();

    var prest = await this.loadPrestador();
    
   
    this.setState({
      prestadores : prest,
      atividades: ativi,
    });
  }

  async loadAtividade(){
    const response = await api.get('atividade');
    
    return response.data.atividades
  }

  async loadPrestador(){
    const response = await api.get('prestador');    

    return response.data.prestadores
  } 

  
  
  render() {

    return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Text style={styles.headerText}>
          <Text style={styles.headerTextBold}>Bem Vindo!</Text>
        </Text>
      </View>

      <Text style={styles.title}>Selecione um serviço</Text>

      <FlatList  
        data={this.state.prestadores, this.state.prestadores}
        style={styles.prestadorList}
        keyExtractor={prestador => String(prestador._id), atividade => String(atividade._id)}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        renderItem={({ item: prestador, atividade })=> (
          <View style={styles.prestador}>
            <Text style={styles.prestadorProp}>Nome:</Text>
            <Text style={styles.prestadorValor}>{prestador.nome}</Text>
            
            <Text style={styles.prestadorProp}>Localidade:</Text>
            <Text style={styles.prestadorValor}>{prestador.endereco.cidade}/{prestador.endereco.estado}</Text>
            
            <Text style={styles.prestadorProp}>Atividades:</Text>
            <Text style={styles.prestadorValor}>{atividade.nome}</Text>

            <TouchableOpacity 
            style={styles.perfilButton}
            onPress={()=>{this.navigatePerfil(prestador)}}
            >
              <Text style={styles.perfilButtonText}>Mais informações</Text>
              <Feather name="arrow-right" size={16} color="#E02041"></Feather>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        )}
      />      
    </View>
  )  

}

}

export default Main;
```

I can render the data individually, but I cannot render it together. The response of the queries comes from the functions loadAtividade and loadPrestador.

loadAtividade response
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EWug.jpg

loadPrestador response
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWMBF.jpg

Comment: Is there any relationship between these two arrays?

Comment: atividade is related to prestador through the id